# Can I add socket to a epoll descriptor while another thread waits on this epoll descriptor?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, epoll

I have several threads, one of them calls `epoll_wait` in a loop, others can open connections that need to be `epoll`'ed by first thread. Is it possible to just add new sockets with `epoll_ctl` while another thread waits in `epoll_wait`?

What will happen in the following scenario:

1. Thread 1 calls epoll_wait.
2. Thread 2 creates a socket(A) and adds it to epoll instance using epoll_ctl.
3. Someone sends some data, socket A becomes ready for read() call.

Will epoll_wait return socket A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will. The whole point of an `epoll` socket is that you don't have to duplicate effort. No snapshotting or use of multiple wait queues is involved.

Under the hood, the epoll socket has its own wait queue. When you block on the epoll socket, you are added to that single wait queue. No state is saved or anything like that. The state is in the epoll socket itself.